# Arkham Origins with Python?

Tags: python, opencv, python-mss

Okay, so today I got nostalgic and started to play Arkham Origns. I get to this part where Deathstroke hands me my butt all the while mocking me, so I try again. But nope, couldn't counter his attacks in time. Apparently, my timing wasn't accurate.

So now it got me thinking, what if I took screenshots of the game using "Python-mss" , train my own haar cascade for the cropped image of the "counter" prompt (a mouse image shows up on the display telling you when to click which button) , go through the screenshots using a for loop and if l get a screenshot with the "counter" prompt, I imitate the mouse buttons using pyautogui.

But I feel that this approach is quite slow ( going through each screenshot and trying to detect the mouse buttons) and of course, primitive. Should I try it anyway? Or should I try to build a CNN in Keras?

I would like you to suggest me other better options. Well, except getting better at the game.

Comment: Nostalgic? For Arkham *Origins*? Not City or Asylum?

Comment: Yea, kinda prefer Origins to city and asylum

Comment: Could you share your code please? There may be some clues here and there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are playing on PC (which you probably are given the nature of the question) you could use a texture pack to replace right click mouse button prompt with something more distinguishable, and non-transparent. Just keep in mind that the prompt will not show up in NG+ or I AM THE NIGHT mode.

On the other hand, the strategy I would use would be to create a Lua script in Cheat Engine 6.7 to automatically counter Deathstroke's attacks.

Also, keep in mind that the final boss fight (if you want to call it that) with Joker is broken, and requires very different timing.